# Big Cartel: Method to remove a country from the shipping dropdown menu?

Tags: bigcartel

First post here, so let me know if I have omitted anything that's needed!

I'm trying to figure out a method to remove a country from the dropdown menu that is available on the cart page on our Big Cartel store, used for selecting the country of delivery.

FYI I'm not a developer, just a hands-on tech type person who helps run a small company.

I'll paste the code below that displays the dropdown. From my understanding, it is pulling the list of shipping countries via an array(?) called country_select.

As I don't have access to that array (confirmed with Big Cartel that I cannot exclude a country using their UI), is it possible to exclude one item when displaying the dropdown list?

```
<div class="cart-shipping">
            <label for="country"><span>Shipping to:</span></label> {{ store.country | country_select }}
        </div>
```

EDIT: hired someone who wrote a script to achieve this.